# Problema Acentuação

Tags: java, tomcat, acentuação, pom

Amigos, estou com um problema, todos os acentos que tem no programa que fiz utilizando tomcat está com "?" como exemplo: Atrav?s, informa??es,?ndices.
no pom eu configurei:

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                 <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

saberiam me dizer o que ainda falta?

Comment: Qual tecnologia de front está usando? Para sabermos se a renderização da página é no servidor ou cliente. Estes dados vem do banco de dados, do próprio Java ou de algum arquivo de properties? Consegue nos mostrar mais trechos do seu código?